# What's this type of Bonsai?

Tags: trees, bonsai

[image]

So I bought this today and forgot to ask what type it is. This is my first bonsai tree and I would love to know how to properly take care of it :)

Comment: Go back and find out what it is!  We could make guesses or get you to send more pictures but the store you purchased this guy knows what he is and how long he has been a bonsai. I tried to blow up your picture to find foreign language!!  Keep your plant watered. Every other day even every day.  Different than normal potted plants. Do not put it in direct sun! Ask when and with what it was last fertilized.  You should definitely sign up for a Bonsai class.  Bonsai is the ultimate task for gardeners.  This guy is a great Bonsai that deserves a knowledgeable master...!

Comment: Did you try to scan the QR code? Maybe it directs to a website with instructions? I am not sure what species it is, and therefore not sure whether you can keep it indoors or not (most bonsai trees are not suitable for indoors). But as stormy says, water it daily (or every other day), the small pot doesn't hold water for a long time. Looks great next to that rock, btw!

Comment: It does say "indoor" on the label, @b.nota .

Comment: @Stephie you have sharp eyes! I didn't see that before you told me.

Comment: @b.nota  My goodness!  Can you DO THAT?  Scan the code?

Comment: @Stephie You are able to read the foreign language?  Of course you are!  Who told the OP to take the plant out of doors?  This is INDOORS at the shop.  These shops that sell plants should be telling people how to care for their new plants and tell them the plant's maintenance history...at the very least.  Pisses me off.  Grins!

Comment: @stormy not really. The readable label just says "Bonsai" and "indoor", the other one is blurry, but that belongs to the Venus flytrap (Dionaea muscipula)in the front. Morgan, I hope that you'll take good care of it and that the photo doesn't show its real place? And I see only three traps, but all of them are closed - I hope that's not the case with all of them?

Comment: Morgan, can we get a close-up of the leaves in good lighting (preferably daylight) and in focus, please? Ideally top and bottom? Your photo is unfortunately quite blurry ("noise", from too little light), which is probably why you didn't get a "real" answer yet, but a lot of "have you tried X" comments. If in the mean time you found an answer (from the store, from the QR code...), you could answer your own question, this is perfectly fine here and on all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: The text on the venus trap label is Dutch, which I can read... But the question is about the bonsai tree, not the venus trap. QR code can be read by smartphone app.